# assigning values to individual string python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to assign values of 100 to individual alphabets (A-L).
Then, im supposed to show the values of each alphabets. Only managed to get certain codes done, not sure how to continue.

```
def inventory():
    startingValues = 100
    partIds = 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'
    stockLevel = [[startingValues] * len(partIds)]
    for i in range(len(partIds)):
        print("Part  Stock Level")
        print(f"{partIds}     {stockLevel}")
inventory()
```

The output should be as such:
Part   Stock Level
A      100
B      100
.
.
.
L      100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the code you want?

```
startingValues = 100
partIds = 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'
stockLevel = [startingValues] * len(partIds)
string = "Part  Stock Level"
for i in range(len(partIds)):
    string = string + " " + f"{partIds[i]}     {stockLevel[i]}"

print(string)
```

This gives exactly the output "Part Stock Level A 100 B 100 . . . L 100"